# what is meaning of member types in stl container?

Tags: stl

My question is based upon the following link:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

What is the actual meaning of member types(`value_type`, `allocator_type`, etc.) ?

I have searched for this in many text books, but no one defines and explains in a clear way.

Please, can anyone explain it with the help of an example or a clear link?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are `typedef`s to the corresponding types that the templated container is using.

For example, `value_type` corresponds to the type of the element that the vector can hold. So `std::vector<int>::value_type` would be `int`, and `std::vector<float>::value_type` would be `float`.

Having the commonly-used types available as a type on the container is useful when the container's type itself is unknown. For example, someone may want to write library code that works equally well with `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`:

```
template<typename TMap>
void insert_default_pair(TMap& map)
{
    map.emplace(typename TMap::key_type(), typename TMap::mapped_type());
}
```